# Picasso error loading image?

Tags: android, performance, listview, picasso

I'm trying to use the Picasso library but it is not working. I think my error is with the `Picasso.with(Context)` i might be using wrong parameter. I included the code for the MainActivity and ListClass. The picture is not loaded and does not appear in the app just white space.

UPDATE!! the " which i was missing has nothing to do with the error. just wrong copy. it gives me error on the `this`

MainActivity;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;







public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   {

    ListView list;
    imageHandler imagess = new imageHandler();

    String[] web = {"Trial "};
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.ic_menu_camera };
    //Drawable[] imageId = { imagess.LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/satelliteegypt-400x240.jpg")};

    Handler handler;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        listClass adapter = new
                listClass(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

ListClass that i used the Picasso library to load the picture from the URL;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class listClass extends ArrayAdapter<String>{



    //Next three lines introduces Variables to use in the class
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    //Constructor to get Web, Image and context to set adapter
    public listClass(Activity context,  String[] web, Integer [] imageId) {

            super(context, R.layout.list, web);
            this.context = context;
            this.web = web;
            this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    //Public method to ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/egyptischemoefti.jpg").resize(60,60).into(imageView").resize(50,50).centerCrop().
                into(imageView);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here error is you are using library in wrong way.

`"`  is not valid here.

Also you have used `.into(imageView)` and `resize(..)` twice.

Try this.

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/egyptischemoefti.jpg").resize(60,60).centerCrop().
            into(imageView);
```

Comment: The ending " is missing in your answer :|

Comment: it was the problem with context. had wrong parameter now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @asdff good luck. As before you are using `this` in `@Override
    public View getView` method so here `this` refers to view not for `Context`. I think now you have understood what was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got the " wrong. Your image URL seems to have been copied wrong. Stuff like 'resize(60,60).into(imageView)' are/should not be part of the URL for the image. They might have come in accidentally.

Use this

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/egyptischemoefti.jpg").resize(60,60).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Edit : 
Maybe the context you are giving to Picasso is not right. You need to give it the activity context that you are initializing in the constructor.

Maybe this :

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/egyptischemoefti.jpg").resize(60,60).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Same error. i just copied it wrong but have it correct in the code @NarayanAcharya

Comment: I just saw the image at that URL. Seems legit. What error are you getting? Can you share the logcat for the error?